# What is to carry ... credential?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> The Duties of a Steward on a Ship Are:
>   The duties of a steward can vary greatly depending on the size of ship he works on. In general, the majority of stewards work in galley or housekeeping departments. They carry a **Merchant Mariner Credential**, or MMC, and are designated as "Ordinary Seaman." Instead of working on deck and navigating the ship, stewards are employed as cooks, waiters, bartenders, chambermaids and more. No prior experience is needed when applying for an MMC.
>
> Source: [Career job description](https://careertrend.com/info-8536298-duties-steward-ship.html)

**Question**: Could you please explain, what they mean "to carry Credential"? Is that some special duty?

Comment: The verb **carry** which means in this context "to have with you on your person" is often used with documents that show a person's legal or work status. Members of trade-unions carry a card that shows their work-class; certain classes are qualified to perform certain tasks.  Sometimes you will see the verb **hold** instead.

Answer (score 2):

The clue lies in the definition:

**noun**
(Usually *credentials*). 
evidence of authority, status, rights, entitlement to privileges, or the like, usually in written form: Only those with the proper credentials are admitted.

Anything that provides the basis for confidence, belief, credit, etc.

Thus a credential is some kind of evidence to indicate that a person has a certain claim or right or status or similar. Identity documents, passports, driving licences and social security cards are all forms of credential.

In the merchant navy, there are various classes of seaman (or woman) and officer. An *ordinary seaman* is the basic or entry level. Stewards who wish to work at sea have to apply for an ID document known as the Merchant Mariner Credential in order to be recognised by shipping companies. It is just a form of identification suitable for the profession they wish to enter.

http://www.dictionary.com/browse/credentials